Segmentation fault in my code SLL Natural Merge Sort in C++
This is my code SLL Natural Merge Sort in C++:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* link;
}NODE;
typedef struct List{
    NODE* first;
    NODE* last;
}LIST;
void Init(LIST &l){
    l.first = l.last = NULL;
}
NODE* GetNode(int x){
    NODE* p;
    p = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (p==NULL){
        printf("Khong du bo nho!"); return NULL;
    }
    p->data = x;
    p->link = NULL;
    return p;
}

void AddLast(LIST &l, NODE* new_ele){
    if (l.first==NULL){
        l.first = new_ele;
        l.last = l.first;
    }
    else {
        l.last->link = new_ele;
        l.last = new_ele;
    }
}
NODE* InsertLast(LIST &l, int x){
    NODE* new_ele = GetNode(x);    
    if (new_ele == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    AddLast(l,new_ele);
    return new_ele;
}
void AddNumber(LIST &l, int a[], int n){
    NODE *p;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        InsertLast(l,a[i]);
    }
}
void ShowNumber(LIST l){
    NODE* p = l.first;
    printf("Day so: ");
    while (p!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",p->data);
        p = p->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void DistributeList(LIST &l, LIST &l1, LIST &l2){
    NODE *p;
    do{
        p = l.first;
        l.first = p->link; p->link = NULL;

        AddLast(l1,p);
    }while((l.first)&&(p->data<=l.first->data));
    if (l.first)
        DistributeList(l,l2,l1);
    else
        l.last = NULL;
}
void MergeList(LIST &l, LIST &l1, LIST &l2){
    NODE* p;
    while ((l1.first)&&(l2.first)){
        if (l1.first->data<=l2.first->data){
            p = l1.first;
            l1.first = p->link;
        }
        else{
            p = l2.first;
            l2.first = p->link;
        }
        p->link = NULL;
        AddLast(l,p);
    };
    if (l1.first){
        l.last->link = l1.first;
        l.last = l1.last;
    }
    else if (l2.first){
        l.last->link = l2.first;
        l.last = l2.last;
    }
}
void NaturalMergeSort(LIST &l){
    LIST l1, l2;
    if (l.first == l.last) return;
    Init(l1);
    Init(l2);
    DistributeList(l,l1,l2);
    NaturalMergeSort(l1);
    NaturalMergeSort(l2);
    MergeList(l,l1,l2);    
}
int main(){
    LIST l;
    Init(l);
    int a[] = {12,2,8,5,1,6,4,15};
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    AddNumber(l,a,n);
    ShowNumber(l);
    NaturalMergeSort(l);
    ShowNumber(l);
}

When I run it, the code reports an error right at this line
Segmentation Here
The code still runs normally when I Debug, but when I enter the NaturalMergeSort function, in the DistributeList function, I encounter a Segmentation fault in the AddLast(l1,p) line.
That's what I got in the terminal when i try to run:
My Terminal
I tried to fix it but it keeps getting this error many times, please help me fix it.

There's almost nothing C++-specific with the shown code, all I can see is that you use references for some function arguments. Everything else is plain C. What resources are you using to learn C++?

If you actually debugged your code, you will see there is a stack overflow error with the data you are using.  NaturalMergeSort calls NaturalMergeSort which calls NaturalMergeSort, etc. etc. until the call stack overflows.  All I did was add a message, and you see the output never ends until the program seg faults.  Also note that a lack of debugging your own code is worthy of a downvote -- you should have been able to detect this yourself.  How to fix the problem is a different issue, but you should have able on your own to figure out what's wrong.

In NaturalMergeSort, suppose l is already ordered, then think about what l1 will be like after "distribution".

A much simpler case that exhibits the problem is {1,2}. This is so small that you can trace through the code "by hand". Test cases should be small and systematic, not large or arbitrary.

Thank you everyone for helping me, I was able to fix the code by reducing the number of input elements and slowly debugging. Thank you very much everyone.

You sure you mean "C++"? Your code is just "C".  C++ doesn't use malloc (it uses new, if at all...), it doesn't use NULL but nullptr and C++ would not use printf... Whoever is trying to teach you C++ is doing a horrible job, and that person should watch Stop teaching "C"

A good C++ design would also hide the Node type inside the list class (it should be invisible from outside the list class). For example have a look at std::list. So your code doesn't only use "C" syntax it also still uses "C" design approaches.

@PepijnKramer - In the case of Visual Studio C++ for 64 bit builds, new is limited to 2GB while malloc isn't  limited, which would be a reason to use malloc in C++ code in some cases. Although std::list doesn't include a node type, it does include std::list::iterator, which can be used to move nodes, such as std::list::splice(). or to access or change data values via an iterator.

@rcgldr I didn't know about that limit, but malloc still needs to be used with care it only can be used for trivially constructible and destructable types.

@rcgldr That limit was a bug : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-new-an-object-more-than-2GB-in-size/10328982#T-ND10337717

@PepijnKramer - thanks for the update. The bug is there in VS 2015, which I'm stuck with on Win 7 Pro 64 bit, but I have VS 2022 on Win 10 Pro 64 bit, so I'll get the update.

@PepijnKramer - the one C++ aspect of the question's code is the pass by reference syntax in the functions.

@rcgldr It doesn't matter really, OP isn't learning C++ anyway and writing "C". This kind of code is really only use by teachers who still teach "C" (e.g. datastructures classes), or by competitive coders. (yuck), and has nothing to do with how C++ should be used.

There are issues with this implementation. DistributeList is recursive, which can cause stack overflow on a large array with short runs. This can be fixed by making it iterative, alternating between L1 and L2. I also ran into data patterns where cycles were created (small circular sub-lists), which seemed to be fixed when I replaced the merge function with known working code. I don't know if the OP made similar fixes.
The questions code is not a natural merge sort. A natural merge sort is bottom up, doing a one time scan to find already sorted sub-lists, and merging them. The questions code needlessly and repeatedly scans the same values over and over. For example if the array is {14,15,12,13,10,11,8,9,6,7,4,5,2,3,0,1}, then L1 ends up with {14,15,10,11,6,7,2,3}, the scan is repeated so that L1 ends up with {14,15,6,7}, and yet again {14,15}. The same process is done for L2, to end up with {12,13}, and only then does the first merge begin.
The following is an example of a bottom up natural merge sort. A small array is used to hold pointers to the first nodes of sorted-sub-lists. apNode[i] points to a list with 2^i sorted sub-lists, or it is null. If not null, then apNode[{0 1 2 3 4 ...}] is a pointer to {1 2 4 8 16 ...} merged sub-lists. This is old code (Windows | Hungarian naming convention), but it works. A single scan at the end would be needed to set a pointer to the last node.
NODE * Merge(NODE *pNode0, NODE *pNode1)
{
NODE *pMrg;
NODE **ppMrg = &pMrg;
    if(pNode0 == NULL)                  /* if either list empty, */
        return pNode1;                  /*  return the other */
    if(pNode1 == NULL)
        return pNode0;
    while(1){                           /* merge the lists */
        if(pNode0->data <= pNode1->data){
            *ppMrg = pNode0;
            ppMrg = &(pNode0->next);
            pNode0 = *ppMrg;
            if(pNode0 == NULL){
                *ppMrg = pNode1;
                break;}}
        else{
            *ppMrg = pNode1;
            ppMrg = &(pNode1->next);
            pNode1 = *ppMrg;
            if(pNode1 == NULL){
                *ppMrg = pNode0;
                break;}}}
    return pMrg;
}

/* size of internal array */
#define ASZ 32
NODE *MergeSort(NODE * pNode)
{
NODE *apNode[ASZ] = {NULL};             /* array of lists */
NODE *pNext;
NODE *pLast;
size_t i;
    if(pNode == NULL || pNode->next == NULL)
        return pNode;
    /* merge nodes into array */
    while(pNode){
        /* set pLast to end of already sorted sub-list */
        pLast = pNode;
        while((pNext = pLast->next) != NULL && pNext->data >= pLast->data)
            pLast = pNext;
        pLast->next = NULL;
        /* merge sorted sub-list into array */
        for(i = 0; i < ASZ && apNode[i] != NULL; i++){
            pNode = Merge(apNode[i], pNode);
            apNode[i] = NULL;}
        if(i == ASZ)                    /* don't go past end array */
            i--;
        apNode[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;}
    /* merge array into a single list */
    pNode = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
        pNode = Merge(apNode[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}

In my benchmarking with variations of data patterns including sequences of 8 increasing numbers I don't see any significant improvement in performance versus a non-natural merge sort that merges nodes into the array one node at a time, and the natural merge sort is a bit slower for pseudo-random values.
#define ASZ 32
NODE *MergeSort(NODE * pNode)
{
NODE *apNode[ASZ] = {NULL};             /* array of lists */
NODE *pNext;
size_t i;
    if(pNode == NULL || pNode->next == NULL)
        return pNode;
    /* merge nodes into array */
    while(pNode){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; i < ASZ && apNode[i] != NULL; i++){
            pNode = Merge(apNode[i], pNode);
            apNode[i] = NULL;}
        if(i == ASZ)                    /* don't go past end array */
            i--;
        apNode[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;}
    /* merge array into a single list */
    pNode = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < ASZ; i++)
        pNode = Merge(apNode[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}

